# Jitterbit Cloud Studio Snowflake Query Transformation Error - qName and root name CASE SENSITIVITY

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jitterbit

Have been trying to configure Snowflake Connector in Jitterbit Cloud Studio (using Cloud agent).

PUT/INSERT data has been progressive. However, got confronted with Startelement() Error when using Snowflake Query to fetch back data into Cloud Studio.

```
Transformation 'Brand to Variable' failed.
StartElement() error, starting element does not match with the root. 
**qName= "brand", root name="BRAND"**
ProcessFlatStream error
```

As the screenshot/error code snippet shows, there is seemingly a bug in Jitterbit.config in in terms of the CASE SENSITIVITY (qName = "brand", root name="BRAND"). Has any one ever got stuck with this type of issue and found a fix for it?

[Error Msg Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKEPe.png)

Answer (score 0):

So for Cloud Studio, there is Jitterbit Preset variable named $jitterbit.transformation.auto_streaming. Use Script to set the value to be 0 or false. Then the case sensitivity bug would be resolved.